# How to disable/enable network adapter from command line on the Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, device-manager

Currently, when I need to disable/enable network adapter I'm performing the following steps:

1. Opening the device manager (<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `devmgmt.msc` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Searching for the required network adapter.
3. Click right mouse button on it.
4. Select *Disable* (or *Enable*) from the popup menu:
   [image]

**How I can disable/enable network adapter from the command line?**

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open up **Command Prompt** as **Administrator** and type the following command line:

```
netsh interface set interface 'INTERFACE NAME' disable
```

References:

[How to enable or disable Wi-Fi and Ethernet network adapters on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-or-disable-wi-fi-and-ethernet-network-adapters-windows-10)

Answer (score 5):

Open up **PowerShell** as **Administrator** and run the following:

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

Get-NetAdapter will list the Network adapter properties

[Get-NetAdapter Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Disable a network adapter by name

```
Disable-NetAdapter -Name "Adapter Name" -Confirm:$false
```

[Disable-NetAdapter Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/disable-netadapter?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Enable Network Adapter by Name

```
Enable-NetAdapter -Name "Adapter Name" -Confirm:$false
```

[Enable Net Adapter Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/enable-netadapter?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Answer (score 0):

### **script to enable and disable network adapter**

hi,
use the below script and save it as .bat file.ex.. (lan.bat)
please change the interface name
cmd > `netsh interface show interface` (this command will show your interface name)

copy below script to notepad and save it as .bat file as said above
`@echo off  (netsh interface show interface name="your interface name" | find /i "enabled")>nul if %errorlevel% equ 0  (netsh interface set interface name="your interface name" admin=disabled)  else (netsh interface set interface name="your interface name" admin=enabled)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).