# How to disable automatic network connection on windows startup?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, networking, internet

So in Linux you need to manually run some commands or write config files to connect to the network. Before these steps you can use the system perfectly fine without a connection. Is something like this possible on Windows 10? Currently, even if I haven't login yet I see a bunch of packets running somewhere. That is: is it possible to use Windows offline without disabling a network adapter or intentionally misconfiguring your connection?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "connection". Linux and Windows can work offline just fine, so your question is not very clear. Or do you mean that you want to disable automatic wifi connection?

Comment: @harrymc automatic Ethernet connection. There is a button to disable Wi-Fi completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the Ethernet, you need to disable the Ethernet network adapter.

That is done in
*Control Panel > Network Connections*, by right-click on the adapter and
selecting "Disable".

Undoing is by similarly selecting "Enable".

For disabling automatically on shutdown, use the following
references to create a shutdown event handler which will run
a batch script to disable the network adapter:

- [Using Task Scheduler to Run a Task Before Shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/165142/using-task-scheduler-to-run-a-task-before-shutdown)
- [How to disable/enable network adapter from command line on the Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1689648/how-to-disable-enable-network-adapter-from-command-line-on-the-windows-10)

Comment: Agree, but the problem is that I need to do that before every shutdown of the working session in which I've enabled the adapter. Is it possible to somehow make the adapter disabled by default, so even if I have enabled it, it will be disabled automatically on shutdown, so on the next startup there will be no connection again? Basically I want the same behaviour as in Linux: no connection by default, unless I manually turned it on.

Comment: I added this to my answer.

Comment: On my Windows 10 machine its Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > left-click on "Ethernet" link (right-clicking does nothing) > click on "Disable" button at bottom.